# Axios post request does not work correctly for token

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a django rest API that uses TokenAuthentication as authentication_class and IsAuthenticated as permission_class.
the following curl command works very well with my API:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/courses/user_profile/  -H "Authorization: Token 5a24a230d66d92d2cfe6612f449ddb5e589d74fa"
```

But whenever I send the same request by axios, I get the *"Authentication credentials were not provided."* error.
My axios config is as follows:

```
const a = await ProfileAPI.post('',
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Token  ${response.data.key}`,
          }
        })
```

in which the profileAPI is defined as:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/courses/user_profile/',
});
```

would you please help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are now using `obtain_auth_token` of the `rest_framework.authtoken` package, the login response should be the dictionary with the following format.

```
{
    "token": "20c8b45a2ffb96fd4e763f01ababfd3732103d35"
}
```

So I think the token value should be `response.data.token`, not `response.data.key`.

```
const a = await ProfileAPI.post('',
    {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Token  ${response.data.token}`,
      }
    })
```